# Can someone explain to me what this code is doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently building an online course and I was having trouble accessing a lesson that is associated with a certain course.

A developer friend of mine solved the problem for me but I'm not really sure why this code works and if there are different ways, more of a Rails conventional way to write this code.

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to course.title, "courses/#{course.id}" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

I am not sure what this part `"courses/#{course.id}"` is doing. Is there a way to write this using a more conventional seeming names route helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the same as `course_path(course)`

This call just figure out the path for you. The expression in your code simply build this path putting together `"courses/"` and the id of the course (but using interpolation, not concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

As Ursus answer explains, `courses/#{course.id}` creates URL directing to specific course path by using string interpolation. For example, if `@courses` variable is an array with Course objects with ids: `[1, 2, 3]`, then you will receive links directing to `"course/1", "course/2", course/3"`.

To replace that interpolation, you can simply write

```
<%= link_to course.title, course %>
```

It will create the same output as `"courses/#{course.id}"`

To learn more about string intepolation, you can start here: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your friend did this:

```
<td><%= link_to course.title, "courses/#{course.id}" %></td>
```

...instead of this:

```
<td><%= link_to course.title, course %></td>
```

...and I have no idea why. The second example is how you use links in Rails. The first example doesn't safeguard you against possible future URL changes.